# Xamarin Forms - Slide out menu to select items

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin forms application search screen that allows a user to select an item from a list. Currently I am using a picklist and the user has to scroll and select and click done. This is using the native controls. Howerver I have noticed in iOS in settings menu etc where the have designed it so that when a user want to select from a list a arrow is shown on the right hand side which takes them to another page to select an item (s) from a list. To me this seems like a better UX.  Here is an ex:

[image]

My question is there something built into this withing xamarin forms? I guess I could create a listview and then on click pass to another page. Any examples are appreciated.

Comment: this is just a ListView in Forms

Comment: Here is simple example of Listview: https://github.com/Srusti-Thakkar/SqLiteXamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in for that, but it's not too hard to achieve this.

To set the disclosure indicator (the arrow), implement a custom renderer derived from `ImageCellRenderer` and override `GetCell`

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
{
    var viewCell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);

    viewCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;

    return viewCell;
}
```

When the user taps that cell you should navigate modally to the view showing the list of languages.

Adding that *Cancel*-Button is not really hard either, but needs another step. You'll need to wrap the new language selection page in a `NavigationPage` and push that `NavigationPage` modally. Furthermore you'll have to add a toolbar item to the wrapped page ([see here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/121691/#Comment_121691)).

Within the page there is a `SearchBar` view and a `ListView` below it. To add the checkmarks, you'll have to implement a custom cell with a custom renderer (derived from `ImageCellRenderer` like the one shown above), setting the `UITableViewCell.Accessory` to `Checkmark` if the custom cell is selected

```
if(item is SelectableCell selectableCell)
{
    var selected = selectableCell.IsSelected;
    viewCell.Accessory = selected ? UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark : UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
}
```

**Please note**: Selectable cell is no Xamarin.Forms stock cell, but one that you have to implement by yourself, including the bindable property `IsSelected`.

This should be basically the steps you need to achieve what you want. I've assumed basic Xamarin.Forms knowledge that is needed to fill the gaps.

Comment: It appears your example above is specific to iOS but it there a cross platform way to accomplish this?

Comment: @Scott Yeah, specific to iOS, that is right. That disclosure indicator is something very iOS-esque.

Comment: Ok so is there a better pattern you would suggest for cross platform? I prefer to not have to write 2 different code bases as I would like to stick with xamarin forms? It appears there are many limitations unless I want to go native

Comment: Having some OS-specific code is quite normal. Usually you would not maintain two code-bases, but only one, but keep your platform code in the platform specific projects within the same solution.